# Possible to use JqMobi for both desktop and mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, mobile-website, jqmobi

we have a site that is running on Jquery and Backbone.

But it is rather slow on the mobile, but i do not want seperate bases for the desktop and the mobile.

I was wondering if jQmobi runs well on desktops as well? I do not care about supporting IE8  and below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's webkit only, so if you only care about Chrome/Safari it works fine, but it does not work on FF/Opera/IE currently.

- note (I'm the lead dev.  I use Chrome desktop for development then test on device)

Comment: thanks a million! this is great. is there any plans to make it cross browser as well? for us, we are ready to use a much smaller/efficient library across the stack, at the expense of older browsers and loss of certain functions.

Comment: jqMobi works fine cross browser.  jqUi does not.  We *may* go cross browser in the future ;) .  But the focus is mobile, so right now the issue is FF mobile and opera mobile do not support the CSS3 properties we require (transitions/transforms).